# How to prevent shadowing and promote given method?

Tags: c#, inheritance, shadowing

In C++ it is done with "using", and in C#?

```
public class foo
{
   public void print(string s) {...}
}

public class bar : foo
{
   // shadowing
   public void print(object o) {...}
}
```

How to promote `foo.print`, so `foo.print` and `bar.print` would be at the same "level" for compiler (for `bar` of course)?

### Update 1

Originally I added a paragraph about common confusion between shadowing and overriding, but then I deleted it, because I thought it will be offensive to readers.

Shadowing is like overloading spanned over inheritance tree. Shadowing is **NOT** overriding.

### Update 2

After shadowing `foo.print` is no longer taken into account when resolving the overloaded method `print`. Promoting `foo.print` would get it back into process -- so when I call `bar_object.print("hello")` the method `foo.print` would be called.

Comment: What do you mean by promote? What do you intend to happen? For `bar.print` to override `foo.print`?

Comment: isn't this an overload? in foo you need a print method that accepts an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your concrete example, `bar.print(object)` indeed "shadows" the more specific `foo.print(string)`:

```
new bar().print("i am a string");
```

This will call the method defined on `bar`, although the method on `foo` would have a parameter that matches the type better.
What happens here is the following: The compiler finds a method on `bar` with the right name ("print"), the right number of parameters (1) and a parameter type to which the passed in parameter is convertable to (`string` can be converted to `object`).
Because of this, there is no reason for the compiler to look further up the inheritance chain.

As far as I am aware, there is no construct similar to C++'s `using`.
If you want to use the method defined on the base class, you basically have three options:

1. On the caller side: Convert the `bar` instance to `foo`:

   ```
   var bar = new bar();
   var foo = (foo)bar;
   foo.print("i am a string"); // Will call foo.print(string)
   ```
2. On the calee side: Inside `bar.print(object)` check the type of the passed parameter:

   ```
   public void print(object o)
   {
       var s = o as string;

       if(s != null)
           base.print(s);
       else
       {
           // Other code.
       }
   }
   ```
3. This will come the closest to the C++ `using`: Actually override or hide the original method in the derived class:

   ```
   public class bar : foo
   {
       public new void print(string s)
       {
           base.print(s);
       }

       public void print(object o)
       {
           // some code
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You don't have to explain what shadowing is :-) I know what it is. Both your solutions are technically correct (thank you), however they are no-go. The first one for obvious reason -- caller would have to know entire inheritance tree by heart (and this is very error prone). The second involves a lot of trickery -- comparing it to C++ `using foo.print` in `bar` definition it makes me look further to other approaches.

Comment: @greenoldman: I just updated my answer - please check for an idea on how to solve it.

Comment: Meanwhile I used the same construct :-). I will keep this question open for a while (to attract other readers), if nothing better will appear, I will accept your answer. I hope it is OK with you.

Comment: @greenoldman: I don't think you will find any simpler solution than just doing public new void print(string s) as shown above.